# Objects contain photo taken from server should reload tableView containing the objects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsobject

I have a tableView in a ViewController containing an array  of objects `Channel`; the array is populated from a json string saved in my CoreData Database

Parsing the json and creating the objects `Channel` I can have typical variable like id, the name of the channel and the members of the conversation; this is the object Channel

```
class Channel: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var members = [Member]()

    var profileImage: UIImage?

    override init() {
       super.init()
    }

    init(id: String, name: String, members: [String]) {
        super.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        for idMember in members {
            let newMember = Member(id: idMember)
            self.members.append(newMember)
        }
    }

    func loadPhoto(id: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        Helper.getImage(id: id) { (imageResult) in
            if let image = imageResult {
                self.profileImage = image
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable profileImage should be taken from a Server with an API, the problem is that when the object has been created parsing the json in the function `getDataFromCoreData()` the `Channel` objects in the array have the variable id, name and members but still don't have the images, so my tableView will have the rows for the various channels but without the profileImage, because of the async call.

In my case to reload the table to visualize the images a made a function `loadImages()` to wait for async call to finish and reload the tableView

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ConversationsViewController: UIViewController {

    var channelList = [Channel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //I get the channelList from a JSON saved like a string in my coreData with a custom function
        channelList = getDataFromCoreData()
        loadImages()
    }

    func loadImages() {
        for channel in self.channelList {
            channel.loadPhoto(id: channel.id) { success in
                if success {
                    self.chatTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
extension ConversationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MessageChannelTableViewCell

        var channel = channelList[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = channel.name

        if let profileImage = channel.profileImage {
            cell.profileImage.image = profileImage
        } else {
            if channel.members.count > 2 {
                cell.profileImage.image = theme.groupChatImage
            } else {
                cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profile-icon")!
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return channelList.count
    }
}
```

I know that the question can be long and boring, but i want to know if there is a better way to do it, and if yes you can tell me to improve my code

Comment: I used **SDWebImage** [https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage] in several projects and works perfectly

Comment: I saw that, but i'm preferring to not have any pods at least :) but thanks for the answer

Comment: Reload each row after you got the image instead of reloading the entire table. You can use the table function **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** for it.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about that :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could reload a single cell instead of the whole UITableView every time:

You should find a way to get the indexPathRow of every cell that needs to download the image and then:

```
let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: indexPathRow, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .none)
```

...take a look at the enum options for the animation to choose the one that fits your app.

EDIT: you could test in the CellForRowAtIndexPath if the image is nil and then load it from your server. In the success closure reload the cell itself... you alredy have the indexPath. use weak self to avoid retained cycles.

Comment: Yeah that can be a solution :)
I'm trying to understand avoiding those retained cycle in these days! How can i use it in my case?

Comment: Example: 
func loadImages() {
        for channel in self.channelList {
            channel.loadPhoto(id: channel.id) { [weak self] success in
                if success {
                    self.chatTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Don't mind me if I ask you what changes having [weak self] instead of not have it? What this better for? Because I still can not understand the theory behind retained cycles :)

Comment: Very very short version :) 
Two objects A and B: A holds a strong reference on B, B (in the closure) holds a strong reference on A. ARC do not deallocate either classes. [weak self] makes "self" weak :D
Al limite contattami che te lo spiego o ti passo qualche link ;)

Comment: Quindi anche utilizzando un weak var a channelList potrebbe funzionare giusto?
In modo tale che il ViewController non abbia una strong reference alla lista?
Come ti contatto per dubbi o altre cose?? :)

Comment: Yes. Mmm ...no private messages on StackOverflow?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to find the way to do it on Stack but I couldn't find one ahahah

Answer (score 1):

There are many many libraries that extend UIImageView to solve this problem:

[AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)
[Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke)
[SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)
[KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Architecturally where they are different from your solution is 1) There is a separate image cache persisted to disk (sometimes NSCache, sometimes not) which prevents downloading the same image repeatedly, but also saves you form having to store everything in the database (you just store the URL).  2) The extension is on UIImageView so image views know how to load a URL and cancel the request if the image view is destroyed before it completes.  They generally offer additional features, such as a placeholder image to use during download, resizing of images etc.  Its not that hard to write your own cache, although I almost always just use one of the pods.  Here is a very simple cache I wrote for a demo project where I didn't want to use a pod:

```
class ImageCache {
    enum Result {
        case success(UIImage, URL), failure (Error)
    }
    static let shared = ImageCache()
    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
    private init() { }
    func image(for url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result) -> ()) {
        guard let image = cache.object(forKey: url as NSURL) else {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
                guard let `self` = self,
                      let image = UIImage.gif(url: url.absoluteString) else {
                    completion(.failure(NSError()))
                    return
                }
                self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSURL)
                completion(.success(image, url))
            }
            return
        }
        completion(.success(image, url))
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should initialize my profileImage variable as an ImageCache
When should I tell him to load the images from server?